# Netbeans code completion full class+namespace VS "use"

Tags: netbeans, ide, code-completion

I am using Netbeans 8.0 for PHP

I try to use code completion feature, when I type

```
new EntityM
```

Netbeans shows:
[image]

great so far, I hit enter on the first option, then Netbeans generates:

[image]

What I want to do:
Instead of generating a full class name (namespace+class name) I want Netbeans to add a **use** statement and a simple class name, this will add:

```
use \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
```

before my class declaration and the generated code will be:

```
$d = new EntityManager($conn, $config, $eventManager)
```

Anyone could advise how to achieve this?

PS: This is exactly how **PHPStorm** works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO not possible now, there is some enhancement in NetBeans' bugzilla. The "workaround" is to let NetBeans insert FQN and then press Ctrl+Shift+I to fix namespaces, this will remove FQN and insert use statements.

Comment: Fair enough, nice trick, worked for variable types, class extends and comments type hinting.